# C#/WPF Grid MaxWidth in relation to screen resolution

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid, gridsplitter

I've got 2 `Columns` that are divided by a `GridSplitter`. And I want to set the MaxWidth of the columns in percentage (e.g. `5*`) but it doesn't work. Is there any other way to do it?

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"  />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Columns"
              Grid.Column="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Height="auto"
              Background="#c1c1c1"
              BorderBrush="#c1c1c1"
              BorderThickness="1"/>
```

Comment: You need a separate column for the splitter.  Come on, lots of examples on MSDN.  Just search on GridSplitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.aspx) documentation for `ColumnDefinition`, `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` are of type `double`, not like `Width` property, which is of type `GridLength` - that's why it supports `Auto`, `*` as valid values for Widtth. So, Specifying MinWidth, MaxWidth interms of percentages is not a straight forward thing.

However, you could write a `Converter`, which can take `Auto, *` as input values and do the math and then set a valid value for MaxWidth.